# Tensorflow stucks at run(init_op) (In distributed environment)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

When I run a program using Estimator in a distributed environment but it stucks at sess.run(init_op) where init_op is just `global_variables_initializer`. More specifically, it stucks at `_extend_graph()` of `session.py` which is

```
def _extend_graph(self):
# Ensure any changes to the graph are reflected in the runtime.
with self._extend_lock:
  if self._graph.version > self._current_version:
    # pylint: disable=protected-access
    graph_def, self._current_version = self._graph._as_graph_def(
        from_version=self._current_version,
        add_shapes=self._add_shapes)
    # pylint: enable=protected-access

    with errors.raise_exception_on_not_ok_status() as status:
      tf_session.TF_ExtendGraph(
          self._session, graph_def.SerializeToString(), status)
    self._opened = True
```

The graph_def.SerializeToString() is quite strange and I take part of them here.

b'\ng\n\x1dglobal_step/Initializer/Const\x12\x05Const*\x12\n\x05value\x12\tB\x07\x08\t\x12\x00R\x01\x00*\x1e\n\x06_class\x12\x14\n\x12\x12\x10loc:@global_step*\x0b\n\x05dtype\x12\x020\t\n\x87\x01\n\x0bglobal_step\x12\nVariableV2"\x0e/job:ps/task:0*\x0b\n\x05shape\x12\x02:\x00*\x0b\n\x05dtype\x12\x020\t*\x1e\n\x06_class\x12\x14\n\x12\x12\x10loc:@global_step*\x11\n\x0bshared_name\x12\x02\x12\x00*\x0f\n\tcontainer\x12\x02\x12\x00\n\xaa\x01\n\x12global_step/Assign\x12\x06Assign\x1a\x0bglobal_step\x1a\x1dglobal_step/Initializer/Const"\x0e/job:ps/task:0*\x11\n\x0buse_locking\x12\x02(\x01*\x07\n\x01T\x12\x020\t*\x1e\n\x06_class\x12\x14\n\x12\x12\x10loc:@global_step*\x14\n\x0evalidate_shape\x12\x02(\x01\nb\n\x10global_step/read\x12\x08Identity\x1a\x0bglobal_step"\x0e/job:ps/task:0*\x1e\n\x06_class\x12\x14\n\x12\x12\x10loc:@global_step*\x07\n\x01T\x12\x020\t\n\xdc\xf3\x0f\n\x05Const\x12\x05Const"\x12/job:master/task:0*\xa9\xf3\x0f\n\x05value\x12\x9e\xf3\x0fB\x9a\xf3\x0f\x08\t\x12\n\x12\x04\x08\xb1\xfe\x01\x12\x02\x08\x01"\x88\xf3\x0f\'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x002\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00&\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x005\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00%\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x001\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x004\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00*\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00%\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00&\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00+\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x006\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00#\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00+\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00;\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x006\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\'\x00\x00

What are the potential reasons for these output? And how can I possibly solve this problem?

Thanks.

---

My distributed settings for estimator is

```
cluster = {'ps': ['10.132.0.3:2222'],
                 'master': ['10.132.0.2:2222']}
os.environ['TF_CONFIG'] = json.dumps(
          {'cluster': cluster,
           'task': {'type': 'master', 'index': 0}, 'tf_random_seed':0, 'environment': 'cloud'})

# This config is passed to estimators.
config = tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig()
```

Comment: There are still some open issues with Estimator (ie, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6132). The output of `SerializeToString()` is normal, that's the binary encoding of your graph. If it's stuck in `extend_graph` suggests that your client can't connect to your remote master. (ie, you did sess = Session("grpc://123") and "123" is not accessible by network)

Comment: Thanks. I work on google cloud with 2 cpus. I have run the mnist_replica on these two machines and it works well. So I think the network itself good. I wonder I have set distributed environment for the estimators in a correct way. I have added them in the problem description.

Comment: you could double-check your environment by using distributed TF without estimator (ie, try to place a variable on ps and add to it from master)

Comment: OK. I will try and show the result later. Thanks.

Comment: I've found the problem: I thought the estimator will create the client server for user but it turned out to be not the case. So when the server is created, the problem is solved. Thanks.